# Join two MySQL tables and group result with php

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have the following code to populate cities in a table.

```
$cities_query = "SELECT city_name FROM city_selection";
$cities_result = mysql_query($cities_query);


echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cities_result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['city_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Now I need to group every city by a region so I created the table called `city_region_selection` and added a `Foreign key` from the new column `"region_id"` in the `city_selection table` to `region_id` in the new table.

I'm now struggling to present this data in a nice html table using PHP.

Is it even possible to populate first a table row with region_name and then some subrows containing cities from that region? Please see this image for details:

[image: http://oi48.tinypic.com/2uq0z9x.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to do a little preprocessing:

```
/* SQL
   SELECT
      city_name,
      region_name
   FROM
      city_selection
      NATURAL JOIN city_region_selection
SQL */

$regions = array();
while ($result->fetch()) {
   if (!isset($regions[$result->region_name])) {
      $regions[$result->region_name] = array();
   }
   $regions[$result->region_name][] = $result->city_name;
}
```

---

### Alternate Method with SQL focus

```
/* SQL
   SELECT
      region_name,
      GROUP_CONCAT(city_name SEPARATOR ',') cities
   FROM
      city_selection
      NATURAL JOIN city_region_selection
   GROUP BY
      region_name
*/

$regions = array();
while ($result->fetch()) {
   $regions[$result->region_name] = explode(',', $result->city_name);
}
```

---

### Help

Note that the `while` syntax is just abridged.  You would probably replace it with

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cities_result)) {
   $regions[$row['region_name']] = explode(',', $row['city_name']);
}
```

... for example

Once `regions` is built, simply do this:

```
foreach ($regions as $region => $cities) {
   echo "<tr><td>$region</td></tr>";
   foreach ($cities as $city) {
      echo "<tr><td class="tabbed">$city</td></tr>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer but i'm not sure im following you. It's no kind of code that i'm used to. I am not able to echo out any data. Would you mind providing me with some more code or an explanation?
Thank's in advance.

Comment: @David edited my answer to answer your specific comment questions.

Comment: Thank's. Still not getting any data echoed, though. But at least I got something to work with..

Comment: Nope. Not even the html table. The page is not even processing if I insert the code :(

Comment: I am not getting an error message. Everything down to the <div> where I place this code is beeing visible in the browser, if I look at the source code. Then it stops. If I take out this line, however at least it's beeing processed. 

 $regions[$row['region_name']] = explode(',' $row['city_name']);

Comment: Do you have `display_errors` on?  Is `error_reporting` set to -1 or some value that includes all errors?  You are (I am) missing a comma after the `','` in the explode.

Comment: Just one more thing before I do that ;) It is only populating one city per region in my rows. Any comments on that?

Comment: @David what does it output when you do `var_dump($cities)`?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Karlstad" }

Comment: My bad, when I do it inside the loop it outputs:
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Motala" } array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Västervik" } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Växjö" } array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Karlstad" }

Comment: What about a var_dump of `regions`?

Comment: @David you're not using the `GROUP BY` clause I added to the query.  This is very important.

Comment: Thank's for taking your time! unfortunately it still outputs the same result. This is my SELECT query result if I run it in an SQL-editor:
http://pastebin.com/3BbbDMjc
And this is my result when running it on my website:
http://pastebin.com/0kwaL8Ju

Comment: @David then what happens when you var_dump `regions` after the `while` loop?

Comment: It outputs the result of the regions followed by the first city connected to it. Just like this: http://pastebin.com/0kwaL8Ju

Comment: @David Are you also using `GROUP_CONCAT(city_name SEPARATOR ',') city_name` in your query?  That's important too.

Comment: Yes i am. I copy-pasted your query and the result is http://pastebin.com/3BbbDMjc when run through an SQL-editor. I'm pulling my hair out. I cannot figure it out. Thank's again for your help so far though!

Comment: @David I don't know.  I ran this exact code and it worked fine for me.  Good luck debugging..

Comment: @David it's almost exactly the same as yours, but here you go http://pastebin.com/4hcgYUMD

Comment: Thank you. It was the SQL query. Now it works, thank you again!